# Strange behavior of Navigation Bar of Split View Controller

Tags: ios, ipad, ios6, uinavigationbar, uisplitviewcontroller

I found rather odd behavior of `UINavigationBar` of `UISplitViewController`. I have a stadard `rootViewController` on the picture below:

[image]

When the bar button is pressed(it is temporarily for debug styled as "Add button"), I add a new Navigation bar(NOTE: I add, I do not replace!) that handles events done on screen.

**Explanation** - the button is pressed and user starts drawing stuff on screen, the new bar is added for interaction to make the drawing mode stop.

**Problem** - however, when I add this bar a strange graphical detail appears where the bar of my `rootViewController` is split in two pieces. Picture below(marked red):

[image]

Is it a known issue or is it there for a reason?

CODE:

```
UINavigationBar *tmpBar = [[UINavigationBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectOffset(CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 1024.0, 44.0), 0, - 44.0)];
UINavigationItem *it = [[UINavigationItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Draw, baby, draw!"];
it.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel target:self action:@selector(cancelDrawing)];
it.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(sendMail)];
tmpBar.items = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:it, nil];

self.canvasBar = tmpBar;

[self.splitViewController.view addSubview:self.canvasBar];
[self.splitViewController.view bringSubviewToFront:self.canvasBar];

[UIView beginAnimations:@"animateBarOn" context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
[self.canvasBar setFrame:CGRectOffset([self.canvasBar frame], 0, 44)];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

**NOTE:** I am not looking for an *alternative* solution, but for **EXPLANATION** why this is happening.

Comment: Why don't u add a UIToolBar in place of a UINavigationBar?

Comment: "Toolbar - Provides a mechanism for displaying a toolbar at the bottom of the screen."

Comment: I have used the UIToolBar at the top a lot of times..one example when I was presenting a modelViewController +  Apple doc dosent say so too.

Comment: OK, that's all nice, but I am not asking for an alternative solution.

Comment: Why are you not presenting a fullscreen view controller from the splitViewController (possibly using a custom animation). It seems very hacky to be changing navigation bars of a split view controller.

Comment: I am not changing it, I am pushing it over the original one, with custom animation. I need the background of the whole VC, that's why I am not presenting a new one modally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second nav bar is added a bit lower than the first, so you are seeing the division in the blue bar.  As for why, I can't say without more information on how you are adding it.

Comment: I added the code, and I don't think I am placing it lower than I should. Also, the "stitch" is visible through the entire animation as the bar comes down.